# Как в данной функции передать не массив, а объект ? Какие изменения в функцию необходимо внести?

Tags: javascript, es5

```
var renderBigPhoto = function (photos) {
  bigPhotoElement.classList.remove('hidden');

  bigPhotoElement.querySelector('.big-picture__img').querySelector('img').src = photos[0].url;
  bigPhotoElement.querySelector('.likes-count').textContent = photos[0].likes;
  bigPhotoElement.querySelector('.comments-count').textContent = photos[0].comments.length;
  bigPhotoElement.querySelector('.social__caption').textContent = photos[0].description;

  commentsDefault.innerHTML = '';

  commentsDefault.forEach(function (comment) {
    commentsContainer.removeChild(comment);
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < photos[0].comments.length; i++) {
    generateCommentTemplate(commentsContainer);

    commentsContainer.querySelector('.social__comment').querySelector('img').src = photos[0].comments[i].avatar;
    commentsContainer.querySelector('.social__comment').querySelector('img').alt = photos[0].comments[i].name;
    commentsContainer.querySelector('.social__text').textContent = photos[0].comments[i].message;
  }
};
```

Comment: весь код тут, он небольшой https://github.com/Resurt/769389-kekstagram-18/blob/module3-task3/js/main.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var renderBigPhoto = function (photo) {
  // change photos[0] to photo everywhere
  ...
}
```